# Toggle class of multiple ids (javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 2 elements that each have different background colors and upon click, I'd like to make them change to a different color.

Here is code that works *if the elements do not already have background-color*:

```
html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <style media="screen">
    .buttons {
      width: 150px;
      height: 50px;
      border: solid 2px #999;
      text-align: center;
      color: black;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

      background-color: red;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="buttonGallery">
    <div id="button_1" class="buttons">
      <p>button_1</p>
    </div>
    <div id="button_2" class="buttons">
      <p>button_2</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $("#button_1").click(function() {
      $('#button_1').toggleClass('selected');
    });
    $("#button_2").click(function() {
      $('#button_2').toggleClass('selected');
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

However, if I give each id a background-color, they do not change color upon click:

```
  <style media="screen">
    .buttons {
      width: 150px;
      height: 50px;
      border: solid 2px #999;
      text-align: center;
      color: black;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    #button_1 {
      background-color: blue;
    }

    #button_2 {
      background-color: green;
    }

    .selected {
      background-color: red;
    }
```

Also is there a way to write one function that turns each element red upon click? (Rather than write a function for each button. I will eventually have 8 buttons.) Thank you! Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: the more specific css selector style takes precedence, so it's getting overwritten.  you can add !important to the end of the style to make it take precedence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all the `.selected` the class will apply each time but due to the selector priority it will be overwritten by `.button`. So there are tones of ways to fix it.

You can use `!important` keyword (not recommended at all)

```css
.selected {
  background-color: red !important;
}
```

---

**NOTE:** You should avoid as much as you can from using `!important` keyboard, but in your particular case this is the best way to do it, but I highly recommend changing your styling method and use the [`pseudo-class`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-of-type) selector for your main classes instead. just like this:

```css
.buttons:first-of-type {
  background-color: blue;
}

.buttons:nth-of-type(2) {
  background-color: green;
}

/* and so on */
```

And use a specific method for your `selected` class something like this:

```css
.buttons.selected {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Or

You can use a straight forward but repetitive approach. So make your `.selected` class selector something like this:

```
#button_1.selected, #button_2.selected /* and so on */ {
  background-color: red;
}
```

---

Also for simplifying your js code you can do as follows:

```js
$('.buttons').click(function () {
  $(this).toggleClass("selected"); // $(this) keyword will refer to the clicked button, each time attribute with class buttons got clicked.
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is CSS Specificity.

The ID selector (#) will have a higher specificity than the class selector (.)
Try changing

```
.selected {
  background-color: red;
}
```

to

```
 #button_1.selected, #button_2.selected {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: A nice explanation of specificity: https://dev.to/emmabostian/css-specificity-1kca

Answer (score 0):

Just add background-color: red !important;

EDIT

you can use this like one function as requested.

```
$('.buttons').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
});
```

```js
    $("#button_1").click(function() {
      $('#button_1').toggleClass('selected');
    });
    $("#button_2").click(function() {
      $('#button_2').toggleClass('selected');
    });
```

```css
    .buttons {
      width: 150px;
      height: 50px;
      border: solid 2px #999;
      text-align: center;
      color: black;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    #button_1 {
      background-color: blue;
    }

    #button_2 {
      background-color: green;
    }

    .selected {
      background-color: red !important;
    }
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <style media="screen">
    .buttons {
      width: 150px;
      height: 50px;
      border: solid 2px #999;
      text-align: center;
      color: black;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

      background-color: red;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="buttonGallery">
    <div id="button_1" class="buttons">
      <p>button_1</p>
    </div>
    <div id="button_2" class="buttons">
      <p>button_2</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the pure JS method.

You'll want to use querySelectorAll('.buttons').

```
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.buttons')
```

This will make a node list of all objects with the class .buttons.

Then you'll want to apply an event listener to each button by using forEach.

```
buttons.forEach(button=>{
button.addEventListener('click', ()=>{})
```

Then you can write a function for when a button is clicked.

```
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.buttons');
buttons.forEach(button=>{
    button.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
        button.classList.toggle('selected')
    })
})
```

This will update automatically as you add elements with a class of buttons.

And then as others mentioned, add !important to the .selected class background-color property.

Comment: Thanks - I'm getting this error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )` for this bit of code `('click', ()=>)`. Can you please explain if I need to anything else?

Comment: Edited my answer to fix the token issue and adjusted for the the fact that you want it to toggle. There is a way to do this without adding !important, but it takes a couple more of lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want add ".selected" class for each button So you can try this one
I hope this will help you a lot.

```
$("button").each(function(){
   $(this).on("click", function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('.selected');
   });
});
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me, but perhaps I'm not fully understanding -- do I need to replace anything your code? (sorry I'm new to coding)

Comment: You can do one thing add class name to button on which you want click event and add Class ".selected". replace "button " with "button.className"

Comment: For your better understanding it is basically getting every button in array and getting click event on each button. if any button is click it will toggle className to itself only.